# Error updating Python to the Latest Version

Tags: python

I get the following error when updating Python to the latest version:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.9.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.9.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the packages list and install the prerequisites:

`sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common`

Add the deadsnakes PPA to your system’s sources list:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Once the repository is enabled, you can install Python 3.9 by executing:

`sudo apt install python3.9`

try to get the output: Python 3.9.0+

`python3.9 --version`

[via](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/)